# Write CSV from array with ANSI from Node

Tags: node.js, csv

I'd like to write an array of objects to an ANSI (windows-1252) encoded CSV. I'm using the fast-csv and iconv-lite packages. Is there a way to do this without going through a buffer or intermediate streams? My code (which writes a ASCII CSV at present) is as follows:

```
csv
    .writeToStream(
        fs.createWriteStream(filename, {encoding: "ascii"}), objectArray, {headers: true})
    .on("finish", function() {
        {console.log("done!");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `iconv-lite`, you can use an `encodeStream` like so:

```
iconv.encodeStream("win1252").pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))
```

in place of the usual `createWriteStream` invocation.